# Parabolic equation with Cauchy boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider the domain $[0,1] \times [0,T]$ and the uniformly parabolic operator $L -\partial_t$ with smooth coefficient. I would like to obtain the existence of the problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&L u -\partial_t u= F(u)& \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $(x,t) \in (0,1) \times (0,T]$}
;\\
& u(1,t)
=f(t) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $t \in \big[0,T\big]$;}\\
& \partial_x u(1,t)
=g(t) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $t \in \big[0,T\big]$;}\\
& u(x,0)
=h(x) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $x \in \big(0,1\big)$.}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
I know that this kind of boundary condition is called Cauchy boundary condition. I have also found some references about it. But some of them are too old and non-English. For example, references [4, 60, 73-77, 87, 96, 97, 105, 117, 118, 129, 138, 139] in the article "A noncharacteristic cauchy problem for the heat equation". May I have some other references concerning the existence problem? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is $F$ linear, bounded?

Comment: I want a smooth and bounded $F$. But I would like to see the existence result for linear and bounded $F$.

Comment: Is there some other hypothesis on $L$? Is $L$ self adjoint/normal, or what do you know about its spectrum?

Comment: No assumption on $L$ except that it has smooth coefficients.

Comment: Is there any possible existence results for the problem with certain assumptions on the parabolic operator or the boundary data?

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means but a general (?) existence result for the abstract Cauchy problem can be found in Fattorini's book (The Cauchy Problem 1984) chapter 2, for example Thm 2.1.1. 
This requires you to have some knowledge of the resolvent operator for the operator $A= L- F$ partially defined on a subset of $L^2([0,1])$ of functions that satisfy also your first 2 constraints. 

I hope an expert can say something more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But I think Theorem 2.1.1 in there only concerns the Cauchy problem (only initial data but no boundary values). Do I understand correctly?

Comment: you can plug in the boundary values in the choice of the Banach space $E$, where the operator $A$ is (partially) defined. See the examples in chapter 1 of Fattorini like the heat equation on a square.

Comment: If all functions are analytic then on can get a local existence (near the vertical segment $x=1$) by the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem, but I don't think global.

Comment: @Andrew I think Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem can not be applied in this case since we have initial and boundary value here.

Comment: @mnmn1993 If the equation is linear by the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem the solution is defined completely by   analytic functions $f$ and $g$ locally on both sides of the line $x=1$, $0<t<T$.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, so the condition $u(x,0)$ can not be added to the equation arbitrarily?

Comment: @mnmn1993 yes.$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 4):

Say that $L=\partial_x^2$ (the heat equation). Your problem is ill-posed in all reasonnable context : it does not admit a solution for generic data taken in spaces $L^2, C^\infty$ or even in distributional spaces, although it does when the data are analytic (Cauchy-Kowalevska).

Let us consider the simplified situation where $F\equiv0$ and $(0,T)$ is replaced by ${\mathbb R}$. Then the solution must obey
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\hat u(x,\tau)=i\tau\hat u(x,\tau)$$
where $\hat u$ is the Fourier transform in the time variable. Then $\hat u$ is a linear combination $$a_+(x)\exp(x\sqrt{i\tau})+a_-(x)\exp(-x\sqrt{i\tau}).$$
Since the ODE (in $x$) is second-order, your really need both exponentials, but one of the exponential is not even a tempered distribution because it grows fast as $\tau\to\pm\infty$. Thus you cannot invert the Fourier transform and recover $u$.

There is a general rule in Boundary-value problems for PDEs. Say that the boundary has a tangent hyperplane at a point $\bar p$. Replace the domain by the corresponding half-space and linearize the PDE at $\bar p$, to obtain a constant coefficient linear PDE and Boundary condition. Then make the Fourier transform in the tangential variables. In order that the problem be well-posed, it is necessary that the resulting ODE by solvable in the space of bounded functions. This rules out exponentials that grow as the normal coordinate enters the half-space. They remains only a few admissible exponentials, whose number must equal the number of boundary conditions.

In your case, there is only one bounded exponential, thus there must be one and only one boundary condition at $x=1$.

Comment: Can you provide a few references for the above-mentioned general rule in boundary-value problems?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain The book by Benzoni and myself concerns the hyperbolic situtation, but the strategy is the same for other type of PDEs. Actually the key word "Lopatinskii condition" is named that way because of Lopatinskii's seminal work on elliptic BVPs.